# How do I create a well formed CSV or XML to succesfully import entries with assets and categories?

Tags: import, plugin-feedme, plugin-import

The source website is in ExpressionEngine and I know how to get data out, but I don't know how to structure it and succesfully import entries into Craft where assets and categories also imported. I have tried the plugin FeedMe (XML) and I also tried the plugin Import (SVG).

How to work with categories and sub categories an how to use multiple assets with import? Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <products>
        <entry>
            <title>My product title</title>
            <slug>my-product-title</slug>
            <body><![CDATA[<p>My body text</p>]]></body>
            <assets>
                <![CDATA[
                    http://www.mywebsite.nl/root/path/image1.png,
                    http://www.mywebsite.nl/root/path/image2.png
                ]]>
            </assets>
            <category>
                <![CDATA[
                   Lightning,
                   Cities,
                   Standard,
                   Special
                ]]>
            </category>
        </entry>
    </products>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used FeedMe successfully and this is what I used. The images have to be already present as assets in Craft(ftp and then update asset indexes). Having the full url in the images part stumped me too. In this example I pulled the images twice because in my EE build I was using the first image of many to create a preview image and in craft I actually created a preview image field.

```
<entry>
    <entry_date>{entry_date format="{DATE_ATOM}"}</entry_date>
    <title>{title}</title>
    <slug>{url_title}</slug>
    <price>{product_price}</price>
    <dimensions>{product_dimensions}</dimensions>
    <description>{product_description}</description>
    <notes>{private_notes}</notes>
    <location>{product_location:title}</location>
    <number>{product_number}</number>
    <message><![CDATA[{product_message}{option}, {/product_message}]]></message>
    <status>{status}</status>
    <category><![CDATA[{categories}{category_name}, {/categories}]]></category>

    <images><![CDATA[ 
    {finalproductimages}
        {filename}.{extension},
    {/finalproductimages}]]></images>

    <preview><![CDATA[ 
    {finalproductimages limit="1"}
        {filename}.{extension},
    {/finalproductimages}]]></preview>



</entry>
```

Comment: Hi @AbbeyDesign, Thanks for your reply. I'm gonna test FeedMe with your export script.